# "In review" or "under review"

Tags: differences, prepositions

What is the difference between *the year in review* and *the year under review*?

Answer (score 6):

One uses ***in review*** when the purpose is simply to recollect or remember events.

One uses ***under review*** when the purpose is to critically scrutinize events- for example to find fault or establish innocence.

Answer (score 0):

**In review** is going through the past in a flash. **Under review** is to assess something.

> European crisis under review.  *this means assessing European crisis*
>
> Last year in review. *This means reviewing the major things that happened in the course of last year.*